# What exactly do the 'allow-discards' and 'root_trim' Linux parameters do?

Tags: ssd, trim

A lot of SSD-related instructions online currently say you should add **allow-discards** and  **root_trim=yes** to your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. I have yet to find one that says *why* you should do that, i.e. what exactly (if anything!) do those parameters do. **Where is the documentation on this and what does it say about those two parameters' purpose?**

According to [Cryptsetup 1.4.0 Release Notes](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/Cryptsetup140#wikimaincol),

> Since kernel 3.1, dm-crypt devices optionally (not by default) support
>   block discards (TRIM) commands. If you want to enable this operation,
>   you have to enable it manually on every activation using
>   --allow-discards
>
> ```
> cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards /dev/sdb test_disk
> ```

but is it the same when passed to the kernel (via GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX)?

**Edit:** [Kernel.org's list of kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) doesn't (currently, Jan 2013, at least) have either of these options.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html Does not give explanation, but a quick procedure...

Comment: As I said, net's full of instructions without explanations. I'm after the explanations, not the procedure.

Answer (score 9):

From my understanding the boot parameter `root_trim=yes` is Gentoo specific. Within `genkernel` there is a script which looks for the parameter and sets the option `--allow-discards` with cryptsetup (see their [git repository](http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitweb/?p=proj/genkernel.git;a=blob;f=defaults/initrd.scripts;h=03e61e0955dcd32f18bccbf6d0352a011c817d0c;hb=e779547b728506a933809e4b03c4ed6b329f8e08#l840)). Furthermore I found many reports of Ubuntu or Debian users which said that it worked without the `root_trim` parameter. I also found no lines in Ubuntus `update-initramfs` script.

So all in all it is *no* boot parameter, but more a parameter to `cryptsetup`.
The documentation of `--allow-discards` can be found in the manpage of [cryptsetup(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/cryptsetup.8.html):

> **--allow-discards**
>    Allow using of discards (TRIM) requests for device.  This option is only relevant for *create*, *luksOpen* or *loopaesOpen*.
>
> **WARNING**: Assess the specific  security  risks  carefully  before
>                 enabling   this  option.   For  example,  allowing  discards  on
>                 encrypted devices may lead to the leak of information about  the
>                 ciphertext  device  (filesystem  type,  used space etc.)  if the
>                 discarded blocks can be located easily on the device later.
>
> Kernel version 3.1  or  more  recent  is  required.   For  older
>                 versions is the option ignored.

Based on this [blog on TRIM & dm-crypt](http://asalor.blogspot.de/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html), TRIM is operation where upper layer (e.g. filesystem) informs the device which sectors are no longer used (do not contain valid data anymore) and that the device does not need to keep that data content.

In Linux terminology is this operation called discard. In the SCSI world it's be referred to as the UNMAP command.

The discard operation can be used for two purposes: thin Provisioning (informs that data area can be returned to allocation pool) and for SSD operation optimization.

Discards is most useful for SSD optimization since the internal architecture uses larger blocks than sectors and that the blocks must be erased before a write operation can be performed. Information about sectors which do not need to keep data is very useful since the filesystem would be able to more effectively organize blocks in such a way that data fragmentation is minimized and also the disk lifetime would increase.

Comment: So, neither of the options is needed if the filesystem isn't encypted? Why two options if all they do is enable one command to work?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the relation between the kernel parameter and the mount/devicemapper option in your updated answer. +1 this time. :)

Comment: This answer is starting to look good. I also found allow_discards in [dm-crypt's current documentation](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob_plain;f=Documentation/device-mapper/dm-crypt.txt;hb=406089d01562f1e2bf9f089fd7637009ebaad589); everything seems to imply it's not a kernel parameter but an option for the dm-crypt device-mapper target. I'm still trying to find out if those can be passed on the linux command line. That would explain the instructions parroted all over, otherwise it is probably just misinformation.

Comment: @JaniUusitalo It really does not make sense to me to make this a (global) kernel paramater. 1) you really want to specify this filesystem/device-specific rather than system-wide, 2) mount/fstab options lets you do so already, 3) at boot time (before the initramfs has mounted your `/` as read/write) you're not likely to need this functionality.

Comment: The kernel parameterizing of allow-discards could be an Archism: apparently [in Arch, you notify GRUB of an encrypted root](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt_with_LUKS#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_disks_.28SSD.29) with (e.g.) "cryptdevice=/dev/mapper/root:root:allow-discards". This being picked up by Ubuntu users might be due to [Arch's wiki being referred to as "Best reference" by Ubuntu wiki's EncryptedFilesystems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems#pagelocation).

Comment: Good answer for the most part but I'm not completely sold on the last paragraph - it implies that the discard option changes the way the file system organises blocks. As I understand it, TRIM will result in the SSD firmware being made aware of the blocks unused by the file system, allowing the SSD firmware to operate more efficiently. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @JaniUusitalo That doesn't seem correct. On archlinux cryptdevice is used to map the encrypted partition to /dev/mapper/crypt_name with: cryptdevice=UUID=<uuid-of-encrypted-partition>:crypt_name:allow-discards . Specifying /dev/mapper/root can't work because it isn't even mapped at that point.